# Can't commit changes to table with Datagrip

Tags: sql, oracle, datagrip

I use Datagrip 2016.3. When I try to alter a value in a table, I can't commit that to the database (a Oracle SQL-DB).

What did I do:
- Setting a cell to /some new value
- Pressing the checkmark icon ('Commit')
- AND/OR pressing CTRL+RETURN
- Closing the tab
- Reopen the tab
- The /new value is gone, the old one still is there.

I tried this with different tables on different Schemes (and different databases). The column is nullable, the entered values are legit. I can modify the values with Oracle SQL Developer.

**EDIT**(20170116)**:**

For most tests after I encountered the problem I tried to change the *COUNTRY* table of the standard *HR* schema of a local oracle installation. The same table could be altered with SQL Developer.

Comment: Please, try DataGrip 2016.3.2 and tell if it's reproduced

Comment: @moscas: Yes. Sorry to say, but the problem still persists.

Comment: please write to maxim.sobolevskiy[at]jetbrains.com and we will continue our discussions with examples there, ok?

Comment: @moscas: Did you received my email?

Comment: yes, and answered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To commit a change to the database the following steps are needed:

1. Enter a row or change a value (the row is marked green)
2. Submit the change to database (the arrow icon with "DB")
3. Commit that change to the database (auto-commit or right-click for the context menu and select commit (checkmark))

Comment: That is a very strange interface. Selecting auto-commit doesn't actually "auto" commit. You still need to press the send to database icon. Not what I think most people would expect.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can auto-commit change in the most recent versions of DataGrip in addition to the accepted answer.  I'm on v2020.2 and these are currently more permanent options:

1. Change the Tx: setting on the query window from `Manual` to `Auto`.
   *Note: this setting will not persist after you restart DataGrip.*

[image]

2. Change it permanently for the database / data source:

- Press the `Data Source Properties` button (shortcut key `Ctrl-Alt-Shift-S`):
  [image]
- Options Tab -> Connection Section -> Transaction Control -> Auto/Manual
  [image]

#2 is a glaring omission to the DataGrip official help document which I've posted feedback for.  So hopefully they'll add it here soon:  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/submitting-and-reverting-changes.html